# when click checkbox update one column as 1 and other as 0 in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
 $addresses = Address::findorFail($addressesId);
    if( $request->has('default_address')) {
        Address::where('id', $addressesId)->update([
            'default_address' => '1',
            // 'default_address' => '0',
        ]);
    }
```

this is my controller,

```
Route::post('/change/{addressesId}', 'DemoUserController@changeAddress');
```

this is my route

what i want is, i inserted various types of addresses and in the index page i display addresses of various users and checked the default address . suppose a user want to change address the user can check the next checkbox then it will be updated as 1 and the previous should be updated as 0 .I did when click the checkbox it updated as 1 its ok but the previous wont updated .how can I solve this please help.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="address_datatable" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Address Type</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
     @foreach($demouser->addresses as $address)                          
       <tr>
         <td>{{$address->address}}</td>
         <td>{{$address->address_type}}</td>
         <td>{{$address->city}}</td>
         <td>{{$address->state}}</td>
            @if($address->default_address == '1')
             <td><input type="checkbox" checked></td>  
            @else
              <form method="POST" action="/change/{{$address->id}}"> 
                @csrf
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="default_address"></td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="position: 
                 absolute;top:160px;right:30px">Save</button>
               </form>
             @endif
             </tr>                                
           @endforeach
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

my view

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear but you can update the address without selecting it twice
just select it and update the record like this

```
 $address = Address::findorFail($addressesId);
    if( $request->has('default_address')) {
      if($request->default_address == 'on'){
         $address->default_address = 1;
         $address->save();
       }
    }
```

Comment: a user can add two types of addresses , in the index page I display all details of the user. the default address already checked and there is also another checkbox for change the default address.I have done , when i click the checkbox it updates as 1 in the db, fine. but i cannot update 0 . ie when I ckick two datas must be updated 1 and 0 for the appropriate rows against the user.